# Taking the cartesian product over multiple pairs efficiently using Apache Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, rdd

### Old context

I am doing a calculation on my dataset that requires every element to be combined with itself, i.e. by performing `mapToPair` on a `JavaPairRDD<Tuple2<String, List<Double>>, Tuple2<String, List<Double>>>` type. This combination is performed using `cartesian` as per:

```java
JavaPairRDD<String, List<Double>> keyvals;
...
JavaPairRDD<Tuple2<String, List<Double>>, Tuple2<String, List<Double>>> combined = keyvals.cartesian(keyvals).filter(tpl -> !tpl._1._1.equals(tpl._2._1));

combined.mapToPair(tpl -> {
   Tuple2<String, String> ids = new Tuple2<>(tpl._1._1, tpl._2._1);

    double result = calculateResult(tpl._1._2, tpl._2._2);

    return new Tuple2<>(ids, result);
}).filter(tpl -> tpl._2 > threshold).saveAsTextFile("result");
```

### New context

I have now expanded the method `calculateResult` to accept three `List<Double>` types (instead of two as in the example above). This requires the dataset to be combined with itself twice. Here, though, `cartesian` seems to fall short.

My question is thus: how can I combine my data (`keyvals`) with itself twice, essentially yielding something that matches `JavaPairRDD<Tuple2<...>, Tuple2<...>, Tuple2<...>>` (psuedocode).

My goal is to call the method `calculateResult(List<Double> s1, List<Double> s2 ,List<Double> s3)` on each cross-combined pair. I think I may not be taking the right approach by trying to expand the example that I have given above using Cartesian, but I don't know what would be the right steps forward.

Unfortunately, I am constrained to using only Spark Java 2.4.x.

Comment: Are you allowed to use Dataframe ? And Sample input and output would help

Comment: I should just be using the Spark Java API. The input is a CSV-file with header: `name, value1, value2, value3, ... ,valueN`. This is mapped to `JavaPairRDD<string, List<Double>> keyvals` from my example. The values are all double precision numbers.

Answer (score 1):

I hope it helps

I have added code inline comments to describe what I am trying to do
I have purpose added `List` instead of `Tuple3` if incase you need to perform more `catesian joins`

```
JavaPairRDD<List<String>, List<List<Double>>> result =
                keyvals.cartesian(keyvals)
                .filter(tpl -> !tpl._1._1.equals(tpl._2._1))
                        //Perform 3rd cartesian
                .cartesian(keyvals)
                        //Skip the common ids from 1st and 3rd keyvals
                .filter(tpl -> !tpl._1._1._1.equals(tpl._2._1))
                        //Map the result top Pair of Ids:List<String> and Values:List<List<Double>>
                .mapToPair((PairFunction<Tuple2<Tuple2<Tuple2<String, List<Double>>, Tuple2<String, List<Double>>>, Tuple2<String, List<Double>>>, List<String>, List<List<Double>>>) tuple2Tuple2Tuple2 -> {

                    //Combine Ids to single List
                    List<String> keys = new ArrayList<>();
                    keys.add(tuple2Tuple2Tuple2._1._1._1);
                    keys.add(tuple2Tuple2Tuple2._1._2._1);
                    keys.add(tuple2Tuple2Tuple2._2._1);

                    //Combine values to single List
                    List<List<Double>> values = new ArrayList<>();
                    values.add(tuple2Tuple2Tuple2._1._1._2);
                    values.add(tuple2Tuple2Tuple2._1._2._2);
                    values.add(tuple2Tuple2Tuple2._2._2);

                    //Return tuple of List of Ids and List of Values which are of fixed size 3
                    return new Tuple2<>(keys,values);
                });

        result.mapToPair(tpl -> {
            Tuple3<String, String,String> ids = new Tuple3<>(tpl._1.get(0), tpl._1.get(1), tpl._1.get(2));
            double result = calculateResult(tpl._2.get(0), tpl._2.get(1),tpl._2.get(2));
            return new Tuple2<>(ids, result);
        }).filter(tpl -> tpl._2 > threshold).saveAsTextFile("result");
```

**Note : Migrating Spark Java code to Spark java DataFrames would shorten your code and reduce complexity**